Non-Shrek film with Donkey
I remember seeing trailers an animated film a long time ago featuring Donkey from the Shrek franchise and other animals (I think there was a lion), but not any other Shrek characters.
I think I also remember its target demographic being somewhat older than that of the Shrek films, and it being fairly poorly received.
Am I dreaming things up or did this film actually exist?

Perhaps a stupid question, but have you looked here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_%28Shrek%29 ?

According to Wikipedia, the Donkey has appeared in these movies/TV episodes (apart from the 4 main Shrek movies):

Shrek The Halls.
Scared Shrekless.
On an episode of Father of the Pride.

Also, on a musical, but it wasn't animation.
I think Shrek wasn't on Father of the Pride. Could it  be the one you're talking about?
